# AngularJS: How to tell if my controller is bound to my ng-repeat directive element? My data is not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-routing

I just need someone to help me understand why my data is not being generated like I am expecting it to. In ajs-partials/add-part.html I am using an ng-repeat directive, but all that is generated when I visit the page is a comment

> <!-- ngRepeat p in parts -->.

in place of where the data should be.

I first attempted to find out if the element with ng-repeat directive is being bound correctly to my controller, but I do not even know how to do that.

Any help to go in the right direction will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Below is the code.

index.js

```
....
<html np-app="app">
...
<div id="view-container" ng-view></div>
...
<script src="/Areas/Machine/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Areas/Machine/scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Areas/Machine/scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Areas/Machine/ajs-modules/app.js"></script>

<script src="/Areas/Machine/ajs-controllers/SchedulingController.js"></script>
<script src="/Areas/Machine/ajs-controllers/PartsController.js"></script>
...
```

ajs-modules/app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['daypilot', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'SchedulingController',
        templateUrl: '/Areas/Machine/ajs-partials/scheduling.html'
    }).when('/scheduler', {
        controller: 'SchedulingController',
        templateUrl: '/Areas/Machine/ajs-partials/scheduling.html'
    }).when('/parts-list', {
        controller: 'PartsController',
        templateUrl: '/Areas/Machine/ajs-partials/parts-list.html'
    }).when('/add-part', {
        controller: 'PartsController',
        templateUrl: '/Areas/Machine/ajs-partials/add-part.html'
    }).when('/add-customer', {
        controller: 'CustomerController',
        templateUrl: '/Areas/Machine/ajs-partials/add-customer.html'
    }).when('/customer-list', {
        controller: 'CustomerController',
        templateUrl: '/Areas/Machine/ajs-partials/customer-list.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

ajs-partials/add-part.html

```
...
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Part Id</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Customer Id</th>
            <th>Material Id</th>
            <th>ProgrammingStatusId</th>
            <th>Diameter</th>
            <th>Length</th>
            <th>Saw Time</th>
            <th>Turn Time</th>
            <th>Mill Time</th>
            <th>QA Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="partsList" class="odd gradeX" data-ng-repeat="p in parts">
            <td>{{ p.partId }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.partNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.customerId }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.materialId }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.programmingStatusId }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.diameter }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.length }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.sawTime }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.turnTime }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.millTime }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.qaTime }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
...
```

ajs-controllers/PartsController.js

```
app.controller('PartsController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.parts = [
        {partId: 1,partNumber: 12304,customerId: 'Fiber Works',materialId: 'steel',programmingTimeId: 5,diameter: 42,length: 208,sawTime: 0.5,turnTime: 5,millTime: 1,qaTime: 1},
        {partId: 2,partNumber: 12303,customerId: 'Tech Tack GO',materialId: 'steel',programmingTimeId: 2,diameter: 36,length: 169,sawTime: 0.5,turnTime: 2,millTime: 1,qaTime: .05},
        {partId: 3,partNumber: 12305,customerId: 'Supreme Machine',materialId: 'steel',programmingTimeId: 3,diameter: 15,length: 117,sawTime: 0.25,turnTime: 1,millTime: .5,qaTime: .05}
    ];
});
```

FYI, my module (app.js) is linking to each view correctly. I just can't seem to figure out why it is "ignoring" the controller.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, try out [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en), it will let you inspect your scopes really easily!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to save confusion and anyone else wanting to implement their angularjs method the same way I did above. Well, the code above is actually correct and it works. It was actually a javascript error that was keeping the angularjs code from executing to the end. So go ahead and refer to my code in the "question" for a correct way to implement a scale-able angularjs app.

Answer (score 1):

try using ng-repeat instead of data-ng-repeat:

```
<tr class="partsList" class="odd gradeX" ng-repeat="p in parts">
```

also you can check if the list is empty in your html using:

```
// controller code
$scope.partsNotEmpty = ($scope.parts.length > 0);
```

html page:

```
<div ng-if="partsNotEmpty">List is empty!</div>
```

Comment: Using ng-repeat and data-ng-repeat did not make any difference. However, when put in the code you suggested above, it indeed displayed "List is empty!". However, when I look at the $scope.parts in the controller, it is not empty. So how do I test that "add-part.html" is bound to "PartsController.js"?

Answer (score 1):

First, add *ng-app* directive (not *np-app*) in the html tag:

```
<html ng-app="app">
...
</html>
```

Then add *ng-controller* directive in the table tag

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" ng-controller="PartsController">
....
</table>
```

Then make sure the JS code looks something like

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
             .controller('PartsController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.parts = [
        {partId: 1,partNumber: 12304,customerId: 'Fiber Works',materialId: 'steel',programmingTimeId: 5,diameter: 42,length: 208,sawTime: 0.5,turnTime: 5,millTime: 1,qaTime: 1},
        {partId: 2,partNumber: 12303,customerId: 'Tech Tack GO',materialId: 'steel',programmingTimeId: 2,diameter: 36,length: 169,sawTime: 0.5,turnTime: 2,millTime: 1,qaTime: .05},
        {partId: 3,partNumber: 12305,customerId: 'Supreme Machine',materialId: 'steel',programmingTimeId: 3,diameter: 15,length: 117,sawTime: 0.25,turnTime: 1,millTime: .5,qaTime: .05}
];
```

});

Put everything together after omitting some irrelevant details not pertaining to your question, you should have something like in the following plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/HNztl648dcGvffGEROSC?p=preview

Comment: Question code has `ng-app` declared. There is no need to introduce a global variable with `var app = angular.module`, that can possibly introduce leaks & collisions.

Comment: "var app" is an angular module. In the module is where I define the routing and binding using ".config". Study "ajs-modules/app.js" and you will know what I am trying to accomplish. Doing this will allow me to have a more scale-able app over time. Also, this method should not require me to explicitly type "ng-controller="PartsController", but it is taken care in the module.config.

Answer (score 0):

The `HTML` does not have the `ng-controller` containing the data declared, so your `ng-repeat` can't access the object array. Just add `ng-controller="PartsController"`, like so:

```
<tbody ng-controller="PartsController">
    <tr class="partsList" class="odd gradeX" data-ng-repeat="p in parts">
```

Comment: Tried this with no success. By the way, isn't that what a module is for? The module $scope is what binds the data between the controller and the view.

Comment: `module` is a angular function for global configs & injecting services/3rdparty/etc, it can't by itself attach model/scopes to the template view. Only directives can attach model/scope to the view, ng-controller is a directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController). If your having no success, whats the error msg in your console?